# Security devices other than firewall and IDS

Tags: encryption, firewalls, ids, threat-mitigation, protection

I was just studying about firewalls and IDS/IPS and had a doubt. Are these the only two major security devices that a company invests in? or are there other equipment and security controls?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @schroeder i know that antivirus software should be installed in every computer to protect from viruses, and that programs should be updated regularly to safeguard the network. Also that it is always recommended to install both IPS (Host based and network based) . Furthermore Bastion hosts and DMZ can be implemented in the network topology (although this again relates to the firewall). Also VPN and leaked line could be used to connect branches
I searched through google and security stack exchange for other devices but could find any, most of it only focus on firewall and IPS.

Comment: You don't solve security by gadgets. Read the classics: https://www.schneier.com/essays/archives/2000/04/the_process_of_secur.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few other choices.  If software is inherently insecure, all you can do is to replace it with something that isn't; or wrap it up in a condom of some sort.  Host-based systems require programs to be invasively, and cooperatively, installed on every client (virus scanners, local network stack IPS).  Network-based systems don't require cooperation from the clients, and try to fix security by parsing traffic.  Some network-based systems require a little bit of cooperation by blocking encrypted traffic for connections that don't submit to scrutiny; and accept the company/ISP's certificate authority (so that the authority at the local boundary can inspect the traffic).

Comment: thanks, i take it that apart from the firewall and IPS/IDS very little other equipment are as effective.

Comment: Read about LANGSEC.  The only real solution is software that has strong protocol specifications, and strong guarantees that it behaves as specified.  In the real world however, organizations have little say in the quality of the software they use.  So everything gets proxied in some fashion; whether it's at the network level (NIDS), or in the network stack (HIDS) or other system calls (virus detect).  I work at a firewall company after being bought from an IDS company.  These things help as much as possible, given the hideous state of the software we all use.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy, Adaptable Security Appliance, DMZ, and Automated Vulnerability Scanners are some items you'll find in the wild that are hardware. There's plenty more security related software items that will help you with research such as Splunk which takes logs and makes them searchable.

Comment: I definitely second this.  Vulnerability maps give a todo list of what need to be secured, and tells you where to look for trouble.  Mining the logs ensures that you don't overlook trouble when it actually happens.

Comment: @GingerBeard well thanks ill check it out, thanks Rob too